# Creating a JSoup class in android using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I know that I have to use ASyncTasks in order to make JSoup work for android, but all examples online illustrate that just by using random jsoup methods in the `MainActivity`.

I want to create a `HTMLParser` class which will contains a function for each element I want to parse but I can't seem to make it work.

My `HTMLParser`:

```
public class HTMLParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private Document doc;


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises").get();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}



public ArrayList<String> findMuscleGroups(){
    ArrayList<String> muscleGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    Elements section = doc.select("a");
    if (section != null) {
        for (Element exercise : section) {
            if (exercise.hasText() && !muscleGroups.contains(exercise.text()) &&
                    exercise.attr("href").contains("exercises/muscle")) {
                muscleGroups.add(exercise.text());
            }
        }
    }
    return muscleGroups;
}


}
```

In my `MainActivity` I want to be able to create a `HTMLParser` object and be able to use something like `ArrayList = htmlParser.findMuscleGroups()`

My `MainActivity`:

```
HTMLParser parser = new HTMLParser();
new HTMLParser().execute();
for (String muscleGroup : parser.findMuscleGroups()){
    textView.setText(muscleGroup + "\n");
}
```

Which won't work. I'm well aware that it isn't supposed to work and there is something I'm missing but I hope you guys can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why did you delete your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967561/jsoup-parsing-class-and-asynctask-in-android)?

Comment: Because that approach wasn't good (I've tried using postexecute, use class variables for the result of each function etc. But neither does that work or is a good design idea

Comment: The problem is still that doc is null?

Comment: Here is the null pointer exception `Elements section = doc.select("a");` . In the other approach when I would try to use the getter on the class variable it would directly give me an empty array (default initialization) and won't call the method to populate it in the onPostExecute(). But that's ok because it was a bad idea to begin with

Also, the code itself in the `findMuscleGroups` function is fine, I've tested it in an empty project

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Probably not the best, but it works so there's that

I've added this to`HTMLParser` class

```
public Document initializeDoc(){
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises").get();
        return doc;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

In `MainActivity` I've created

```
private volatile Document doc = null;
private volatile HTMLParser htmlParser;
```

variables, and added the following in the `onCreate` method

```
    htmlParser = new HTMLParser();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doc = htmlParser.initializeDoc();
        }
    });
    try {
        t.start();
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And needless to say, calling `htmlParser.findMuscleGroups(doc)` works as expected